# How to analyze resource consumption in a timeline with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, timeline

I have a phone calls list divided by phone line with call start and end time like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| LINE1 | 08:01 | 08:03 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| LINE2 | 08:02 | 08:50 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| LINE1 | 08:04 | 08:07 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| LINE2 | 08:55 | 09:00 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to graphically analize line usage during the day to find overlaps between lines, I expect a timeline for each phone line with their busy slots.

[image]

I really cannot understand if this is possible with Excel, because the horizontal bar chart seems not good for this purpose.

Comment: Is [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/149791/timeline-chart-in-excel) of any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating GANTT Chart (Timeline) From Start Time and Duration](https://superuser.com/questions/787429/creating-gantt-chart-timeline-from-start-time-and-duration)

Comment: The duplicate is a good clue but not a complete solution.  This problem needs the ability to have multiple periods for each line with each period similarly colored.  That part isn't obvious from the other solution.

Comment: Then I think you need to update your post and focus just on that part of the question so we can see why it isn't a dupe. As it is, the question (alone) is a dupe I think.